# Error in creating Order Programmatically, Magento 2

Tags: magento2, programmatically, create-order

I am creating order at controller action, just to test if its working or not as:

```
class Save extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
 /**
    * @param Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
    * @param Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product
    * @param Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey $formkey,
    * @param Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote,
    * @param Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
    * @param Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService,
    */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formkey,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagement,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory $customerFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Service\OrderService $orderService  
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_product = $product;
        $this->_formkey = $formkey;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->quoteManagement = $quoteManagement;
        $this->customerFactory = $customerFactory;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
 
    /**
     * Create Order On Your Store
     * 
     * @param array $orderData
     * @return array
     * 
    */
    public function createMageOrder($orderData) {
        $store=$this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $websiteId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
        $customer=$this->customerFactory->create();
        $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
        $customer->loadByEmail($orderData['email']);// load customet by email address
        263135
        if(!$customer->getEntityId()){
            //If not avilable then create this customer 
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId)
                    ->setStore($store)
                    ->setFirstname($orderData['shipping_address']['firstname'])
                    ->setLastname($orderData['shipping_address']['lastname'])
                    ->setEmail($orderData['email']) 
                    ->setPassword($orderData['email']);
            $customer->save();
        }
        $quote=$this->quote->create(); //Create object of quote
        $quote->setStore($store); //set store for which you create quote
        // if you have allready buyer id then you can load customer directly 
        $customer= $this->customerRepository->getById($customer->getEntityId());
        $quote->setCurrency();
        $quote->assignCustomer($customer); //Assign quote to customer
 
        //add items in quote
        foreach($orderData['items'] as $item){
            $product=$this->_product->load($item['product_id']);
            $product->setPrice($item['price']);
            $quote->addProduct(
                $product,
                intval($item['qty'])
            );
        }
 
        //Set Address to quote
        $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
        $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($orderData['shipping_address']);
 
        // Collect Rates and Set Shipping & Payment Method
 
        $shippingAddress=$quote->getShippingAddress();
        $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)
                        ->collectShippingRates()
                        ->setShippingMethod('freeshipping_freeshipping'); //shipping method
        $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo'); //payment method
        $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false); //not effetc inventory
        $quote->save(); //Now Save quote and your quote is ready
 
        // Set Sales Order Payment
        $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
 
        // Collect Totals & Save Quote
        $quote->collectTotals()->save();
 
        // Create Order From Quote
        $order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
        
        $order->setEmailSent(0);
        $increment_id = $order->getRealOrderId();
        if($order->getEntityId()){
            $result['order_id']= $order->getRealOrderId();
        }else{
            $result=['error'=>1,'msg'=>'Your custom message'];
        }
        return $result;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $orderData=[
                    'currency_id' => 'USD',
                    'email' => 'user@w3classes.info', //customer email id
                    'shipping_address' =>[
                    'firstname' => 'Test', //address Details
                    'lastname' => 'User',
                    'street' => '123 main street',
                    'city' => 'Demo',
                    'country_id' => 'US',
                    'region' => 'xxx', // replace with region
                    'postcode' => 'XXXXX', // replace with real zip code
                    'telephone' => '9999999999',
                    'save_in_address_book' => 1 // If you want to save in address book
                    ],
                    'items'=> [ //array of products for which you want to create order.
                    ['product_id'=>'5','qty'=>2]
                    ]
                    ];

       $orderID = $this->createOrder($orderData);
       echo $orderID;
    $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
    $resultRedirect->setPath('frontname/index/index');
    return $resultRedirect;
}
```

Almost all links available are explaining same:

https://www.w3classes.info/create-order-programatically-in-magento-2/
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-order-programmatically.html

but when I do this I am having error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text::validateLength() must be of the
> type string, null given, called in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php
> on line 80 and defined in
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php:141
> Stack trace: #0
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php(80):
> Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text->validateLength(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Attribute),
> NULL) #1
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Validator/Attribute/Data.php(131):
> Magento\Eav\Model\Attribute\Data\Text->validateValue(NULL) #2
> /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Validator/Constraint.php(54):
> Magento\Eav\Model\Validator\Attribute\Data->isValid(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor))
>
> ## 3 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Validator.php(59): Magento\Framework\Validator\Constraint->isValid(Object(Magento\Customer\Model\Customer\Interceptor))
>
> ## 4 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/ in /var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Text.php
>
> on line 141

I did setup:di:compile
cache:flush
generated deleted but not working.

Can somebody help to find issue please.

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/create-order-programmatically-in-magento-2/ in case that helps

Comment: you declare a method to create an order as `createMageModel($orderData)` while you call `$orderID = $this->createOrder($orderData);` to create one. Please fix your code first.

Comment: Yes even I corrected it, Its same @RendyEkoPrastiyo